# ADB without USB connection

Tags: adb

The micro-USB port of my Xperia Arc with ICS it's broken. How can I enter to ADB by wireless, without connecting the cable? I am not root, and I need to enter to ADB to root my phone. I can connect to my phone from my PC by SSH. Or there's a another way to root it?

Comment: The easiest way is to get a warranty replacement phone. :)

Comment: In general though, physical damage isn't convered by warranty. I also wonder how one *charges* a phone with a broken USB port

Comment: I can charge the battery with a external charger for batteries.

Comment: @elm390 have you tried a different USB cord? Have you tried charging it using a wall charger?

Comment: It's not the USB cable. The pins of the port are totaly broken.

Answer (score 1):

There are apps out there to help you do this:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exi.adbmngr&hl=en
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.naooh.adbwireless&hl=en
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.com.wxtech.adbwireless
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easyadb

as far as I know, this is the only way to use ADB without using a USB cable. All of these apps however, require root.

If I were in your situation, I would try to get the warranty on the device. It would be a lot of screwing around to get and working without a USB cable. If you try rooting your device and you mess it up, you risk bricking the device all together, which then voids your warranty. I would at least try to get the warranty, the worst that could happen is they say no.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks. You're right. That apps require root, and it's possible to connect with ADB wirelessly without root, but I need to pair it before, connecting it with USB, and that's not an option for me.

Comment: @elm390 Your best option is just to try to get the warranty on the device, the work arounds for this are going to be pretty messy and time consuming. Using adb over a network allows for all sorts of security risks if proper precautions are not taken.